# Return matching item from within nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have array of grouped by scheduledOn data as below

```
[{
scheduledOn: "2020-02-05T00:00:00"
matches:
{id: 1, homeTeamName: "BLUE", homeTeamId: 1, homeScore: 1, awayTeamName: "Red", awayTeamId: 2, …}
{id: 2,homeTeamName: "Red", homeTeamId: 2, homeScore: 1, awayTeamName: "Yellow", awayTeamId: 3, …}
},
{
scheduledOn: "2020-01-06T00:00:00"
matches:
0: {id:3, homeTeamName: "BLUE", homeTeamId: 1, homeScore: 0, awayTeamName: "Yellow", awayTeamId: 3, …}
}]
```

I would like to return one matches object(Not an array) that match with selected id

**Possible Solution I tried 1:**

```
matches.map(match => match.matches
              .find(m => m.id === selectedId))
```

this returns:

```
 [{

    id: 1, homeTeamName: "BLUE", homeTeamId: 1, homeScore: 1, awayTeamName: "Red", awayTeamId: 2, …
    }]
```

but I want this to be just an object instead of array.

**Possible Solution I tried 2:**

```
matches.map(match => match.matches
              .filter(m => m.id === selectedId))
              .map(match => console.log(match
```

)

this returns:

```
 [
    {id: 1, homeTeamName: "BLUE", homeTeamId: 1, homeScore: 1, awayTeamName: "Red", awayTeamId: 2, …}
    ]
```

But this also returns as array.

Is there a way that I can have matched id object instead of array?

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may flatten all `matches` properties into single array with [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and search through it:

```js
const src = [{"scheduledOn":"2020-02-05T00:00:00","matches":[{"id":1,"homeTeamName":"BLUE","homeTeamId":1,"homeScore":1,"awayTeamName":"Red","awayTeamId":2},{"id":2,"homeTeamName":"Red","homeTeamId":2,"homeScore":1,"awayTeamName":"Yellow","awayTeamId":3}]},{"scheduledOn":"2020-01-06T00:00:00","matches":[{"id":3,"homeTeamName":"BLUE","homeTeamId":1,"homeScore":0,"awayTeamName":"Yellow","awayTeamId":3}]}],
      itemWithId2 = src.flatMap(({matches}) => matches).find(({id}) => id==2)
      
console.log(itemWithId2)
```

Though, you should bear in mind, it [may fail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility) (just like so many other cool things) in Microsoft browsers (at least until IE passed away).

If that is the case, you may use `arr.reduce((r,{matches}) => r.concat(matches), [])` instead of `flatMap()`.

Though, when dealing with large arrays, nested finds, suggested by @Zohaibljaz would be [more performant](https://jsbench.me/5ak6b1wwoc/1).

My implementation of it would be something *unacceptably non-readable*:

```js
const src = [{"scheduledOn":"2020-02-05T00:00:00","matches":[{"id":1,"homeTeamName":"BLUE","homeTeamId":1,"homeScore":1,"awayTeamName":"Red","awayTeamId":2},{"id":2,"homeTeamName":"Red","homeTeamId":2,"homeScore":1,"awayTeamName":"Yellow","awayTeamId":3}]},{"scheduledOn":"2020-01-06T00:00:00","matches":[{"id":3,"homeTeamName":"BLUE","homeTeamId":1,"homeScore":0,"awayTeamName":"Yellow","awayTeamId":3}]}]

let objectHavingIdOf2 = {}

src.find(({matches}) => 
  matches.find(item => 
    item.id == 2 ? 
    (objectHavingIdOf2 = item, true) :
    false))
    
console.log(objectHavingIdOf2)
```

Comment: You're most welcome. Take a look at extended version of my answer if performance does matter to process large arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You use `find()` twice

```js
const matches = [{
scheduledOn: "2020-02-05T00:00:00",
matches:[
{id: 1, homeTeamName: "BLUE", homeTeamId: 1, homeScore: 1, awayTeamName: "Red", awayTeamId: 2 },
{id: 2,homeTeamName: "Red", homeTeamId: 2, homeScore: 1, awayTeamName: "Yellow", awayTeamId: 3 }]
},
{
scheduledOn: "2020-01-06T00:00:00",
matches:[{id:3, homeTeamName: "BLUE", homeTeamId: 1, homeScore: 0, awayTeamName: "Yellow", awayTeamId: 3 }]
}];


const selectedId =  3;
const required = matches.find(match => 
                  match.matches.find(m => m.id === selectedId));
console.log(required);

   // if you wanted nested object, add another `.find()`
   console.log(required .matches.find(m => m.id === selectedId));
```

Comment: It returns {scheduledOn: "2020-02-05T00:00:00", matches: Array(2)}
scheduledOn: "2020-02-05T00:00:00"
matches: 
0: {homeTeamName: "BLUE", homeTeamId: 1, homeScore: 1, awayTeamName: "Red", awayTeamId: 2, …}
1: {homeTeamName: "Red", homeTeamId: 2, homeScore: 1, awayTeamName:

Comment: i want only match data

Comment: This is what you asked in 1st version of question

Comment: I think I did not put a question right. Is there a way that I can only find one matches object?

Comment: @JakeKwon I added what you wanted. See the updated answer

Comment: Yevgen Gorbunkov was the one I was looking for thx for the help though

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple recursive function to help you with:

```js
function findById(arr, id) {
    return arr.find(a => {
        if (a.matches && a.matches.length > 0) {
            return a.id === id ? true : findById(a.matches, id)
        } else {
            return a.id === id
        }
    })
}

// call this method with your data
findById(data, 1)
```